# Database doesn't save the data?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, entity-framework

I have database made in visual studio 2015 and i using entity framework 6, my code to insert is :

```
Database1Entities database = new Database1Entities();
Table t = new Table()
{
    name = textBox1.Text
};
database.Tables.Add(t);
database.SaveChanges();
dataGridView1.DataSource = database.Tables.ToList();
```

this is working , but when i close the program and reopen it database is empty

Comment: Probably you have the database copied from the project directory to the output directory.

Comment: @Steve how can i fix this?

Comment: If you have the database file listed between your project files then right click on it and see its properties. Check the property "Copy to output directory". It should be "Never" or "Only if newer"

Comment: Use localdb with a proper connection string.